# Spotlight says it is indexing an external drive, but actually no search

Tags: spotlight, external-disk, ntfs

Spotlight says it is indexing:

```
% mdutil -s /Volumes/TOSHIBA\ EXT

/Volumes/TOSHIBA EXT:   Indexing enabled.
```

There is a `.Spotlight-V100` folder:

```
.
├── Store-V2
│   └── BC758E30-9A07-4193-BEE7-43915CAF38B4
│       ├── 0.directoryStoreFile
│       ├── 0.directoryStoreFile.shadow
│       ├── 0.indexArrays
│       ├── 0.indexCompactDirectory
│       ├── 0.indexDirectory
│       ├── 0.indexGroups
│       ├── 0.indexHead
│       ├── 0.indexIds
│       ├── 0.indexPositions
│       ├── 0.indexPostings
│       ├── 0.indexUpdates
│       ├── 0.shadowIndexGroups
│       ├── 0.shadowIndexHead
│       ├── Cab.created
│       ├── Cab.modified
│       ├── Lion.created
│       ├── indexState
│       ├── journalExclusion
│       ├── journals.assisted_import_post
│       ├── journals.assisted_import_pre
│       ├── journals.health_check
│       ├── journals.live
│       ├── journals.live_priority
│       ├── journals.live_system
│       │   └── retire.1
│       ├── journals.live_user
│       │   ├── retire.44
│       │   └── retire.80
│       ├── journals.migration
│       ├── journals.migration_secondchance
│       ├── journals.repair
│       ├── journals.scan
│       │   ├── retire.13
│       │   ├── retire.2
│       │   ├── retire.3
│       │   └── retire.5
│       ├── live.0.directoryStoreFile
│       ├── live.0.directoryStoreFile.shadow
│       ├── live.0.indexArrays
│       ├── live.0.indexCompactDirectory
│       ├── live.0.indexDirectory
│       ├── live.0.indexGroups
│       ├── live.0.indexHead
│       ├── live.0.indexIds
│       ├── live.0.indexPositionTable
│       ├── live.0.indexPositions
│       ├── live.0.indexPostings
│       ├── live.0.indexTermIds
│       ├── live.0.indexUpdates
│       ├── live.0.shadowIndexArrays
│       ├── live.0.shadowIndexCompactDirectory
│       ├── live.0.shadowIndexDirectory
│       ├── live.0.shadowIndexGroups
│       ├── live.0.shadowIndexHead
│       ├── live.0.shadowIndexPositionTable
│       ├── live.0.shadowIndexTermIds
│       ├── mds64-crash-state
│       ├── permStore
│       ├── psid.db
│       ├── reverseDirectoryStore
│       ├── reverseDirectoryStore.shadow
│       ├── reverseStore.updates
│       ├── shutdown_time
│       ├── store.db
│       ├── store.updates
│       ├── store_generation
│       ├── tmp.Cab
│       ├── tmp.Lion
│       ├── tmp.SnowLeopard
│       ├── tmp.spotlight.loc
│       └── tmp.spotlight.state
└── VolumeConfiguration.plist

13 directories, 61 files
```

But the search does not actually work. The driver is in NTFS format, driven by Paragon NTFS.

```
% diskutil info .
   Device Identifier:        disk2s1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk2s1
   Part of Whole:            disk2
   Device / Media Name:      Untitled 1

   Volume Name:              TOSHIBA EXT

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Volumes/TOSHIBA EXT

   File System Personality:  UFSD_NTFS
   Type (Bundle):            ufsd_NTFS
   Name (User Visible):      Windows NT Filesystem

   Partition Type:           Windows_NTFS
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported

   Total Size:               1.0 TB (1000202043392 Bytes) (exactly 1953519616 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        857.6 GB (857565757440 Bytes) (exactly 1674933120 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes
   Allocation Block Size:    4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    No
   Internal:                 No
```

The problem has been bothering me for long, as none of my external drivers were successfully indexed in the past. Is it a problem of the NTFS driver?